# tu tv texture coordinates larger than 1.0 ? __ (OBJ format)

Tags: opengl, 3d, data-modeling, modeling, wavefront

I want to understand how OBJ format dealing with texture coordinates.

example:

```
vt 1.000000 1.005200
vt 0.467300 1.709900
vt 0.923800 1.994400
vt 0.500000 1.002600
vt 0.371400 1.000000
vt 0.438100 2.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.467300 1.709900
vt 0.105000 1.159500
vt 0.434600 1.002300
```

i understand values should range from (0) to (1.000000) to cover Texture image file from 0% to 100% for each X and Y. (tu tv)

But i find some values in array are above 1.000000, and sometime below 0.000000

How should i deal with these values to stay between 0 and 1 ?

Answer (score 5):

This kind of texture coodinate value indicates that the texture shall be repeated. In the cases of the obj-file

```
vt 0.438100 2.000000
```

the v-part shall be repeated twice.